# Child Activity problem for media player in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have an child activity inside tab host navigated through parent activity of current tab, in that child activity i have one video view loaded with remote url using setVideoUri method.

The problem is showing alert ,  if video view not able to play the video means in default android os through an alert "Sorry , can`t play this video".

 That alert is not shown inside chid activity throws window activity token exception , but if i launched it as separate activity instead of child as main activity it throws an alert properly.

i don`t know how to resolve it , if any one have idea please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue... ActivityGroup is a mess...

Comment: i tried but not yet implemented...